# What are underlying containers?

Tags: c++

I was using priority_queue's in a project, and I decided to use a functor for the initialization, but looking on the internet I found this:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > pq;
```

I already used it and works, but I'm not really sure why the `std::vector<int>` is used there and what **underlying containers** are and how you manage them (I looked for information, but I don't get the idea).

Comment: Does the [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) not help?

Comment: The `priority_queue` has to save data somehow, and it uses a `vector` for that. You can also use a `list` or anything else that fulfills the requirements. You never manage these underlying containers, `priority_queue` does that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` is not really a container, but a *container adaptor*, that is, it takes a container and build upon it a different interface.

The *underlying container* is, naturally, the container that it adapts. By using the C++ template magic you can change the `std::vector` into `std::deque` and everything will just work.

About what container to use, the same rationale of `std::vector` vs `std::deque` applies: the `std::priority_queue` part does not contain the values, it just presents them in a peculiar way.

Comment: But the priority_queue wasn't implemented as a heap? Why then using a vector? I think I'm missin something...

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido, it is implemented as a heap, but where do you think the contents of the heap are stored? They have to be stored somewhere, they don't just float around magically inside your computer.

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido: A heap is usually implemented as a way to look at the objects inside a linear list. Look a the `std::make_heap()` function, for example, that will build such a heap in any container.

Comment: `priority_queue` requires random access, so `std::list` is no good.

Comment: Okay, I thought the heap was implemented as a pure binary tree and not with a container from the STL. This clarifies my doubts!

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido: Since a heap tree is always complete, it makes sense to store it in a linear list, where the children of node `n` are at positions `2*n + 1` and `2*n + 2`, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests to me that the priority queue data structure is using a vector to hold onto the values.  It's being sorted using the greater method so that higher values appear first in the vector, decreasing in order as you go.

It could use another data structure if that made sense, but in this case it chose to use a vector.